# Skew the image using the openCV

Tags: изображения, opencv

I want to skew the image, similar to the picture:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык и добавьте метку языка

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33502869/8324991

Answer (score 1):

Используйте аффинное преобразование [warpAffine](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983)

Матрицу скоса может составить сами

```
1  ctg(theta)
0  1
```

или рассчитать её с помощью [getAffineTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8f6d378f9f8eebb5cb55cd3ae295a999), если есть три пары соответствующих друг другу точек